# When i created and downloaded the zip file, while open the downloaded file extension is missing using php

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

I created a zip file which contains the documents and text file. when i tried with this code:
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$zip1->renameName($filename, $name.'-'.$version.'.'.$ext);

When i open the downloaded file in local system [Local system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAlPL.jpg)it shown the name as Apache-2.0.49 but in server[Server screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufyOJ.jpg) it displayed correctly like Apache-2.0.49.txt

Answer (score 0):

Do you have option enabled to show known extensions?
If I understood correctly your problem, in windows explorer the saved file has no extension.
Go tools > folder view > view & enable to show known extensions.

Comment: I need to get download filename as Apache-2.0.49.txt not as Apache-2.0.49 in local system